Python Get index of a list of substrings when comparing with known string
I have a know string which gets extracted from a WindowsPath and a given list of substrings.
string = ABC1234

The list contains e.g.
list = ['DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']

I would like to get the index of the string in the list (here: 1) as I need this index for a selction in another list and use its entry.
Thanks very much!!!

But that string doesn't exist in the list

You could do something like this:
s = "ABC123"

for i, val in enumerate(['DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']):
    if val in s:
       match = i
       break
else:
    match = None

You could save yourself the second lookup if you did:
s = "ABC123"

list1 = ['DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'JKL']
list2 = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']

for key, val in zip(list1, list2):
    if key in s:
        lookup = val
        break
else:
    lookup = None

